# My internal CSS won't work

Tags: css, html

When I try to run my HTML document, the CSS won't seem to work. I've tried the HTML and CSS validators and nothing seems to work out. I don't know if this is a glitch or anything, but how can I fix this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Website Title</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
body {background-color: red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>1st Biggest Heading</h1>
<h2>2nd Biggest Heading</h2>
<h3>3rd Biggest Heading</h3>
<h4>4th Biggest Heading</h4>
<h5>5th Biggest Heading</h5>
<h6>6th Biggest Heading</h6>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<br>
<a href="https://www.google.com/">This is what you click on</a>
<img src="Image.png">
<img src="Image.png" width="307" height="507">
<img src="Image.pngh" width="307" height="507" alt="My nice internet speed">
<p style="color:orange"><br>This is an orange paragraph.</p>
<p title="HEY, I'M RIGHT HERE!!!!"><br>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1 style="font-size:60px;">Heading 1</h1>
<hr>
<pre>
My Bonnie lies over the ocean.

My Bonnie lies over the sea.

My Bonnie lies over the ocean.

Oh, bring back my Bonnie to me
</pre>
<p style="background-color:green;">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p style="font-family:verdana;">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p style="text-align:center;">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p><b>This is a bold paragraph</b></p>
<p><strong>This is important text</strong></p>
<p><i>This is italic text</i></p>
<p><em>his is emphasized text</em></p>
<p><mark>This is mark text</mark></p>
<p><small>This is small text</small></p>
<p><del>This is deleted text</del></p>
<p><ins>This is inserted text</ins></p>
<p><sub>This is subscript text</sub></p>
<p><sup>This is supersscipt text</sup></p>
<p>And the book said,<q>Hello!</q></p>
<blockquote cite="http://www.worldwildlife.org/who/index.html">
For 50 years, WWF has been protecting the future of nature.
The world's leading conservation organization,
WWF works in 100 countries and is supported by
1.2 million members in the United States and
close to 5 million globally.
</blockquote>
<p><abbr title="World Health Organization">WHO</abbr> was founded in 1948. 
</p>
<address>
Written by John Doe.<br> 
Visit us at:<br>
Example.com<br>
Box 564, Disneyland<br>
USA
</address>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try making external CSS file, html would be easier to understand and u can easily "debug" and find errors

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: works just fine here. Whats the problem?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, halfer. Thanks for the advice, I'll try it out.